# How to translate "blouse" to Chinese?

Tags: translation, word-requests

I'm researching names for many different clothes in Chinese, and when I reached the word **blouse**, seems like I've reached a dead end and, consequently, a need of an explanation. Just to make myself crystal clear, I meant women blouse in particular.

[This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blouse) on blouse still makes me doubt if the translation is right in there.

Two different frequent words I've found in the dictionaries for this word are **女衬衫** and **女短衫**. Both give similar search results picture-wise, so maybe there is a different word meaning blouse and only blouse.

Thanks for any clue or help.

Comment: "女衬衫" is good, no such word as 女短衫.

Comment: [WIKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blouse): Today, the word most commonly refers to a girl's or woman's dress shirt. In this case, 一 Hong Kong Chinese call it 女裝恤衫, which translated to Mandarin would be 女衬衫 or 女裝衬衫

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In Paris, a very slovenly, loose, drawn frock, with most capacious
> sleeves, had been introduced called a blouse. Some of our priestesses
> of the toilet seemed emulous of copying this deshabille, with some
> slight alterations, but we never wish to see it on the symmetrical
> form of a British lady. ["Summary of Fashion for 1822," in Museum of
> Foreign Literature and Science, Jan.-June 1823]

British Ladies, Beware the Blouse upon thy form!

blouse: 女士衬衫
smock: 罩衫
frock: 连衣裙